# IF statement WITH inside postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I got this

```
DECLARE
inserted_user authentication.users;
inserted_favorite user_settings.favorite_beneficiary;    
BEGIN
        IF $6 = 'xxxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' THEN
            WITH inserted_user AS (
                INSERT INTO authentication.users (id, email, first_name, last_name, phone_number, role_id, additional_information)
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
                ),inserted_favorite AS(
                INSERT INTO user_settings.favorite_beneficiary (user_id, beneficiary_id)
                VALUES ($1, $8)
                )
        END IF;
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'unauthorized';
    END;
```

But I got this message error,
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 16:     END IF;

Did I miss something ?
Can I write it on this way ?

Comment: You're missing a query after your `WITH`, a CTE must be followed by a SELECT/INSERT/...

Answer (score 3):

Your CTE ("with clause") doesn't have a final query. You need to use:

```
WITH inserted_user AS (
    INSERT INTO authentication.users (id, email, first_name, last_name, phone_number, role_id, additional_information)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
) --<< no second CTE here
INSERT INTO user_settings.favorite_beneficiary (user_id, beneficiary_id)
VALUES ($1, $8)
```